# Why does Twitter say I've got tweets, but then pull the football away?

Tags: twitter, twitter-api, twitter-integration

My site (listed on my user's page) shows this on my twitter widget when I hover: "This page has been shared 15 times. View these tweets"

This actually makes sense, because I have mentioned it in about that many tweets. However, when I click the link to view those tweets, though, the page navigated to says, "Results for [my site]: No Tweet results for [my site].

Does it hide self-tweets? Or what is the issue here?

Comment: When you click the link, where does it take you? can you show the url?

Comment: https://twitter.com/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.awardwinnersonly.com&f=realtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These particular tweets are just going unindexed by the search service -- not all tweets are indexed.

> Please note that we may not show every Tweet in search results pages.

[Reference](https://support.twitter.com/articles/66018)